# Can we cache the Facebook friend images in Chrome?

Tags: facebook, image, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

We are working on one chrome extension, in which we have FB friend import functionality. 
Now whenever the extension loads it shows all the FB friends images, so for loading these images from FB takes time. We want to minimise the images loading time. 
Is there any way to achieve this? Can we cache the images to the chrome cache & read them from the cache on 2nd time load?

I also dont think this is the solution for the same. 
But wanted to check is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Let the chrome decide itself what and how to cache, it's the best strategy.

Comment: I also think this way.. but it is taking much time to cache..

Answer (score 2):

I guess you’re loading the images by pointing to `http(s)://graph.facebook.com/userid/picture`?

Well, Facebook delivers these URLs with caching headers as follows,

```
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate 
Expires:       Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT    
Pragma:        no-cache
```

These are for the Graph API redirect URL – Facebook is forbidding caching here, so that the browser has to look up these resources every time again. The final image URL on their CDN, to which these URLs redirect with a `Location` header – *those* have the following headers regarding caching,

```
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT    
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600  
Expires:       Thu, 13 Sep 2012 08:07:52 GMT
```

So you *could* try and require the CDN URLs in your app upfront, and then use these as image URLs in your app’s HTML pages – then the browser won’t have to make a request every time to see if the cached version of the image URL is still valid, but can serve it from it’s cache straight away.

CDN URLs *should not* be used over longer time spans – they *can* change; but for a shorter amount of time it’s probably safe to use them, because they will not change willy-nilly without a good reason. F.e., the user changing their profile pic might be such a reason – but caching them for up to an hour or so could be a compromise that makes the user experience while using your app better.

But the drawback of doing so is, that your app will have to make an API request for each friend’s image initially, to *get* the CDN profile pic URL – and that’s time-consuming as well, if you do it for large number of friends. (Although batch requests or an FQL multi-query might be able to shorten that to *one* HTTP request instead of multiple ones.)

Comment: This will be the case for webapps we can use CDNs, but we are working on the chrome extension, so how we can use CDN for the extensions?